# Способы исключить определенное ключ:значение объекта, передаваемого в качестве аргумента в функцию

Tags: reactjs, post, react-hook

Есть функция, которая выполняет POST-запрос

```js
const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useMutation((data) => axios.post(API_URL_UPDATE, JSON.stringify(data)));
  const handleSubmit = async (values, { resetForm }) => {
    debugger;
    await mutateAsync(values, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        ....
      },
      onError: () => {
        ....
      },
    });
  };
```

К ней в value, из формы, прилетают следующие значения:

```js
values:
password: "Dgdjqje#4"
password_again: "Dgdjqje#4"
recovery_key: "?84e0n9LBvaHd4QxiCn0soFVKg6tSkS0I"
```

Все значения условные (взятые с потолка). Я не хочу, что бы в запросе участвовал элемент password_again.
Т.е привести value к следующему виду:

```js
values:
password: "Dgdjqje#4"
recovery_key: "?84e0n9LBvaHd4QxiCn0soFVKg6tSkS0I"
```

Вопрос в том, как можно (и можно ли?) это сделать имея существующую выше функцию?

Answer (score 0):

Всего то нужно было деструктурировать параметры

```js
const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useMutation((data) => axios.post(UPDATE_PASSWORD, JSON.stringify(data)));
  const handleSubmit = async ({ password_again, ...values }, { resetForm }) => {
    values.password = sha256(values.password);
    await mutateAsync(values {
      onSuccess: () => {
        ....
      },
      onError: () => {
        ....
      },
    });
  };
```

где password_again убирается из объекта values